# Connection to HBase from client machine

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running Hadoop and HBase in real distributed mode with 1 master node and 2 data nodes.
When from client I try to connect to HBase with the Zookeeper I.P. of the Master node I am unable to do but it works when I use the Zookeeper I.P. of the other two nodes.

I checked for HQuorumPeer process id and found it was running on all machies.

Kindly, help me to understand this process.

Answer (score 0):

At lease I'd recommend to start with `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` configuration property value check.

- Please be sure you deployed client configuration which includes full quorum servers list.
- You shall be absolutely sure configuration is the same for all cluster nodes.
- Configuration available to client outside cluster shall be the same as inside cluster.

BTW what is the reason of such failures in accordance to your application logs?